# Why the denseness of norm attaining operator is important?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I plan for studying norm attaining operators, Lindenstrauss property A and B, property $\alpha$, $\beta$, and so on... Before do it, I wanna understand why these properties are important.

I know it starts from Bishop-Phelps theorem, but I don't know why the denseness of the set of norm attaining operators in the set of linear operator is important. What I want is something like: if we know the denseness, then we can characterize the original space by only considering norm attaining operators or something else.

Any useful links or comments should be appreciated